# Get object from database based on time period using Criteria?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date, criteria

I want to retrieve object from my database based on **house_id** and **month/year**. I'm storing full date in SQLite database. There should be single result for each month. This is my code:

```
public static Costs getCosts(Date lookUpDate, House house){
        Costs costs = null;
        Session sess = mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
         try {
             tx = sess.beginTransaction();

             // create criteria builder
             CriteriaBuilder builder = sess.getCriteriaBuilder();
             // create criteria
             CriteriaQuery<Costs> query = builder.createQuery(Costs.class);
             // specify criteria root
             Root<Costs> root = query.from(Costs.class);
             query.select(root).where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("house"), house),
             builder.equal(root.get("date"), lookUpDate))); //where month/year equal to lookUpDate
             costs = sess.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();

             tx.commit();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
```

How should I adjust it, so that Criteria will be looking for specific month and year?

I'm really looking for solution how to change my `Criteria` so that it will look for specific month and year rather than selecting all possible costs list and then going through each object comparing dates.

**UPDATE:**
Working code based on François LEPORCQ answer:

```
public static Costs getCosts(Date lookUpDate, House house) {
        Costs costs = null;

        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalendar.setTime(lookUpDate);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date monthStart = new java.sql.Date(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        myCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                (myCalendar.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        Date monthEnd = new java.sql.Date(myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

        System.out.println("Start: " + monthStart);
        System.out.println("End: " + monthEnd);
        Session sess = mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();

            // create criteria builder
            CriteriaBuilder builder = sess.getCriteriaBuilder();
            // create criteria
            CriteriaQuery<Costs> query = builder.createQuery(Costs.class);
            // specify criteria root
            Root<Costs> root = query.from(Costs.class);
            query.select(root)
                    .where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("house"), house),
                            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), monthStart),
                            builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), monthEnd)));
            List<Costs> costsList = sess.createQuery(query).getResultList();
            if(!costsList.isEmpty()){
                costs = costsList.get(0);
            }

            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            System.out.println(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }

        return costs;
```

As a `lookUpDate` parameter I was passing modification date(`LocalDate.now()`) and was checking if there are any records already existing this month.

Comment: From an sql perspective, you want values where the date field is greater than or equal to the 1st day of that year-month and less than the first day of the next year month.

Comment: I understand it, but I just don't know how to implement it into Criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo code

```
lookupStartDate = 01/month/year
lookUpEndDate = lookupStartDate + 1 month

where date >= lookupStartDate and date < lookUpEndDate
```

Use java.util.Calendar to add one month to your start date

try something like this

```
...

//I assume that the day of your lookupStartDate is the first day of month
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
myCal.setTime(lookUpStartDate);    
myCal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);    
Date lookUpEndDate = myCal.getTime();

...

query.select(root).where(
    builder.and(
        builder.equal(root.get("house"), house),
        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("date"), lookUpStartDate),
        builder.lowerThan(root.get("date"), lookUpEndDate)
    )
);

...
```